# Reading the configuration array of a MAX7000 PLD

Tags: jtag, intel-fpga

Well, I have a little problem in my hands, I need to clone an Altera Max EPM7128ELC84, luckily the PLD comes in a socketable PLCC84 package and has a JTAG interface.

Now my question: what approach should I take? this can be done?

I have:

- A generic JTAG-USB adapter
- The means to make a socket with the cables attacehd to the JTAG
- The [datasheet](http://www.altera.com/literature/ds/m7000.pdf)
- A little experience programming FPGAs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Altera Quartus software is unlikely to recognise your USB JTAG hardware.

If you have a parallel port it's very easy to make an Altera JTAG interface, I have a design [here](http://www.leonheller.com/Blaster/Blaster.zip). Terasic makes a low-cost Altera USB JTAG interface.

If the CPLD hasn't been protected you should be able to read it with the Quartus software.

Comment: If it is a commercial product they probably protected their code.

Comment: It is in a light-gun controller from an arcade machine, I'll look at your schematic tomorrow. Thanks for the info

Comment: A side question: do you use this JTAG pinout http://www.hardwarebook.info/JTAG#Pinout_.2810_pin.29 ?

Comment: I use the standard Altera pinout. Details are included in those design files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Altera USB blaster.  Then read it out as @Leon Heller suggsted.